# How to add token in the Header for the python azure function app Http response and to get the status code of 200. Then it has got to the main code

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, http-headers, bearer-token

How to get the Token from the user and we pass in its python azure HTTP trigger function app and once the status code is 200 then only it has to go to the main function code.

This is what I am thinking of:
[image]

Comment: You can make use of authorization keys from the portal that consists of access level code which we can pass through headers and if that access code is valid, then it returns the response.

Comment: what authorization keys?? can you share the code or method if its possible!

Comment: Please see this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-python#http-auth

Answer (score 0):

> How to get the Token from the user and we pass in its python azure HTTP trigger function app and once the status code is 200 then only it has to go to the main function code.

You can make use of Authorization Keys functionality in Azure functions (Python, .NET, etc.)

In the Http Trigger Request URL, you have to send the Authorization code and value.

That you can get it from the Azure Function App Portal:

[image]

For allowing access to all functions in your function app using a single authorization key or you need an individual key to every function in your function app, all it depends on the Authorization scopes (keys) used in the Function request URL.

Refer [Working with Client Identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=in-process,functionsv2&pivots=programming-language-python#working-with-client-identities) in Azure Functions for user authentication/authorization setting-up.